# How to reverse engineer ETH POW

Tags: proof-of-work, merkleization

If I store 10 blocks from Ethereum, with the block difficulty, mixHash and nonce etc. Transactions etc. Is it possible for me to back trace that the information I have stored is actually correct and matches the information that is actually on the blockchain? So essentially a Merkle tree.

What I want to validate is; that the data I sit on matches what is on the Ethereum blockchain.

This will always be retrospective. So if I'm testing block 2, I already have the information of the next block (in this case block 3).

I haven't stumbled upon any resources on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's the library [eth-proof](https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof) that allows creating proof, like transaction inclussion in a block, or storage content from an address at a given block.